# AWS Glue - Boto3 create trigger issue

Tags: python, boto3, aws-glue

I am trying to create a glue trigger from boto3 create_trigger function. The issue is coming against StartOnCreation parameter. When I remove this parameter, the trigger is created successfully. But adding this gives the error: "Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "StartOnCreation", must be one of: Name, Type, Schedule, Predicate, Actions, Description". My code is as below:

```
client = boto3.client('glue')
response = client.create_trigger(
        Name=arguments['TriggerName'],
        Type='CONDITIONAL',
        Predicate={
            'Logical': 'AND',
            'Conditions': [
                {
                    'LogicalOperator': 'EQUALS',
                    'JobName': arguments['PreviousJobName'],
                    'State': 'SUCCEEDED'
                },
            ]
        },
        Actions=[
            {
                'JobName': arguments['JobName'],
                'Arguments': arguments['ArgumentsDict']
            },
        ],
        Description='string',
        StartOnCreation=True
    )
```

I am adding this parameter as I need to create the trigger on Activated state so that I can fire this on event programmatically without having to enable this from console. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is it case sensitive by any chance? Have you tried with "true" instead of "True".  If you can provide a sample code that you are using, i can try in my env.

Comment: Well, value True is mentioned in boto3 documentation. You can use the same code by just replacing the parameter values by any dummy ones.

Comment: Yes this seems to be a bug.When I tried get_trigger I didn't received this property in the definition. Better cut a ticket with AWS support team